# Replace attribute value using some complicated match expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to replace xml tags that look like this: `<indicator itype="ST" ind="U"/>` with `<indicator itype="ST" ind="HELLO"/>`. The xslt stylesheet I'm using looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                    version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match = "@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select = "@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match = "indicator[@itype='ST' and  @ind='U']">
    <xsl:attribute name = "ind">
      <xsl:text>HELLO</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet doesn't work and the processor throws an exception. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace an attribute value, then you need to match the attribute node. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="indicator[@itype='ST']/@ind[.='U']">
        <xsl:attribute name="ind">
            <xsl:text>HELLO</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<indicator itype="ST" ind="HELLO"></indicator>
```

Comment: @Björn Lindqvist: I'm glad it was helpful.